# Implementing a game of guessing words in Python

Tags: python

So I am stuck with the part of checking if the letter is present in the word or not. The game needs to let a person guess a letter in the word, and tell if this letter is present in word or not(5 attempts only)

```
import random
i=0
WORDS= ("notebook","pc", "footprint")
word = random.choice(WORDS)
print(len(word))
while i<5:
    inp = input("What's your guess for a letter in the word?\n")
    for j in range(0,len(word)):
       if inp == word[j]:
          print("Yes, we have this letter.")
       else:
          print("No, we don't have this letter.")
    i=i+1
```

The expected output would be one sentence, either confirming that the letter is present in word, or disproving. However, the actual output is that is prints one sentence per each of letters in the given word, like this:
What's your guess for a letter in the word?
p
Yes, we have this letter.
No, we don't have this letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try regular expression:

```
import random
import re
i=0
WORDS= ("notebook","pc", "footprint")
word = random.choice(WORDS)
print(len(word))
while i<5:
    inp = input("What's your guess for a letter in the word?\n")
    res = re.findall(inp, word)
    length = len(res)
    if length == 0:
        print("Your guess is wrong :( ")
    else:
        print(f"You guess is right :) ")
    i +=1
```

here the output of regular expression is a list so you can do whatever you want with it, e.g. hangman game or ...

Comment: Hmm, i havent seen regular expressions before

Comment: Here is useful tutorial on regex: [RegEx](https://github.com/ziishaned/learn-regex)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking against each letter of the word (and thereby printing it each time), just check whether the letter is `in` the word:

```
while i<5:
    inp = input("What's your guess for a letter in the word?\n") 
    if inp in word:
        print("Yes, we have this letter.")
```